# How to extract features using VGG16 model and use them as input for another model(say resnet, vit-keras, etc)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, vgg-net

I am a bit new at Deep learning and image classification. I want to extract features from an image using VGG16 and give them as input to my vit-keras model. Following is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))

for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

from vit_keras import vit
vit_model = vit.vit_b16(
        image_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
        activation = 'sigmoid',
        pretrained = True,
        include_top = False,
        pretrained_top = False,
        classes = 2)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        vgg_model,
        vit_model,
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = tfa.activations.gelu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = tfa.activations.gelu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = tfa.activations.gelu),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid')
    ],
    name = 'vision_transformer')

model.summary()
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer embedding is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 8, 8, 512)

I'm assuming this error occurs at the merging of VGG16 and vit-keras. How will rectify this error for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot feed the output of the `VGG16` model to the `vit_model`, since both models expect the input shape `(224, 224, 3)` or some shape that you defined. The problem is that the `VGG16` model has the output shape `(8, 8, 512)`. You could try upsampling / reshaping / resizing the output to fit the expected shape, but I would not recommend it. Instead, just feed the same input to both models and concatenate their results afterwards. Here is a working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from vit_keras import vit

IMAGE_SIZE = 224
vgg_model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

vit_model = vit.vit_b16(
        image_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
        activation = 'sigmoid',
        pretrained = True,
        include_top = False,
        pretrained_top = False,
        classes = 2)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
vgg_output = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(vgg_model(inputs))
vit_output = vit_model(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([vgg_output, vit_output])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = tfa.activations.gelu)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = tfa.activations.gelu)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = tfa.activations.gelu)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
print(model.summary())
```